# How can I make object values dynamic with reduce?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to restructure the output of a XML api

currently I am hardcoding the object values so that they match with what is returned from the api

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const data = convert.xml2json(body, { compact: true, spaces: 4 });
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    const output = json.Products.Product;
    const products = output.reduce((acum: any, element: any) => {
        const obj: any = {};
        obj.EAN = element.EAN._text;
        obj.Title = element.Title._text;
        acum[element._attributes.Id] = obj;

        return acum;
    }, {});
    console.log(products);
}
```

This would be a problem if the api changes, how can I make the obj.values dynamic?

Comment: If you're keeping the same name can't you just take the key and the value and use that to stuff the `acum`? Noting that with the (un-tagged) TS factor I'm out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of `output` and `products ` and mention which exat properties are dynamic? Because there's a nested `EAN._text` and `_attributes.Id`. So it's not exactly clear

Comment: Output: https://hastebin.com/ikayoqomaw.css products: https://hastebin.com/qonusiniwu.bash - I would like all properties of the output to be in products along with their values

Comment: And `_attributes.id` will always be there?

Comment: Yes, it's always there, thats why I like the object name to be the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each object to get `_attributes.Id` and [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) of the object to separate variables. Loop through the object and create a new object with the same `key` but `_text` as value.

```js
const input=[{_attributes:{Id:"2205"},EAN:{_text:"7081019328418"},Title:{_text:" MaCo Choco's mini mix"},Brand:{_text:"MaCoFood"},Shortdescription:{_text:"Een heerlijke traktatie! Romige ijssticks gecoat in 4 soorten "},Fulldescription:{_text:"Belgische chocolade: puur, donkere melkchocolade, melkchocolade met amandelnoten en witte chocolade. Dikke laag Belgische melkchocolade Met natuurlijk Bourbon vanille-extract 12 stuks, om uit te delen! "},Image:{_text:"https://www.mupload.nl/img/wf8s4hxr4lor.jpg"},Weight:{_text:"12 stuks"},Price:{_text:"2.65"},Category:{_text:"Diepvries"},Subcategory:{_text:"IJs"},Subsubcategory:{_text:"IJsjes"}},{_attributes:{Id:"2206"},EAN:{_text:"7081011195254"},Title:{_text:"MaCo Kauwgom­balbeker ijs"},Brand:{_text:"MaCoFood"},Shortdescription:{_text:"Vanilleijsjes met aardbeiensaus en een kauwgombal"},Fulldescription:{_text:"Vanilleroomijs met aardbeiensaus Met een kauwgombal onderin "},Image:{_text:"https://www.mupload.nl/img/pr9fi79s4.jpg"},Weight:{_text:"6 stuks"},Price:{_text:"1.69"},Category:{_text:"Diepvries"},Subcategory:{_text:"IJs"},Subsubcategory:{_text:"IJsjes"}}];

const output = input.reduce((acc, { _attributes: { Id }, ...rest }) => {
  const obj = {};
  for(const key in rest)
    obj[key] = rest[key]._text
                  
  acc[Id] = obj;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `reduce` and forEach

First take the `id` from `_attributes` key and use it as a `key` on final object and than using `forEach` add the remaining values on that key ( The one which is created by id ) as key/value pair

```js
let data = [{ _attributes: { Id: '2205' },EAN: { _text: '7081019328418' },Title: { _text: ' MaCo Choco\'s mini mix' },Brand: { _text: 'MaCoFood' },Shortdescription:{ _text:'Een heerlijke traktatie! Romige ijssticks gecoat in 4 soorten ' },Fulldescription:{ _text:'Belgische chocolade: puur, donkere melkchocolade, melkchocolade met amandelnoten en witte chocolade. Dikke laag Belgische melkchocolade Met natuurlijk Bourbon vanille-extract 12 stuks, om uit te delen! ' },Image: { _text: 'https://www.mupload.nl/img/wf8s4hxr4lor.jpg' },Weight: { _text: '12 stuks' },Price: { _text: '2.65' },Category: { _text: 'Diepvries' },Subcategory: { _text: 'IJs' },Subsubcategory: { _text: 'IJsjes' } },{ _attributes: { Id: '2206' },EAN: { _text: '7081011195254' },Title: { _text: 'MaCo Kauwgom­balbeker ijs' },Brand: { _text: 'MaCoFood' },Shortdescription:{ _text: 'Vanilleijsjes met aardbeiensaus en een kauwgombal' },Fulldescription:{ _text:'Vanilleroomijs met aardbeiensaus Met een kauwgombal onderin ' },Image: { _text: 'https://www.mupload.nl/img/pr9fi79s4.jpg' },Weight: { _text: '6 stuks' },Price: { _text: '1.69' },Category: { _text: 'Diepvries' },Subcategory: { _text: 'IJs' },Subsubcategory: { _text: 'IJsjes' } },]

let final = data.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let {'_attributes' : {Id}} = inp
  let temp = {}
  Object.keys(inp).forEach(key=>{
    if( key !== '_attributes' ){
      temp[key] = inp[key]['_text']
    }
  })
  op[Id] = temp
  return op
},{})


console.log(final)
```